# Why is there a logic variable at the end of my list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate `pick_slots(Puzzle, Slots)`. `Puzzle` is a list of lists, in which the elements are `'_'` and `'#'`. For example `[['#', '_', '#'], ['_', '_', '_'], ['_', '#', '_']]`. The predicate should holds when `Slots` is the lists of lists that splits at token `'#'`, for example the predicate will hold for the given `Puzzle` if `Slots` is `[['_'], ['_', '_', '_'], ['_'], ['_']]`.

My code is:

```
pick_slots([], _).
pick_slots([H|Rest], R) :-
    split(H, '#', Result),
    append(Result, R, R2),
    pick_slots(Rest, R2).
```

`split(S, T, R)` holds when `R` is list of lists that `S` splits at token `T`. For example if `S` is `['_', '#', '_']`, `T` is `'#'`, then `R` is `[['_'], ['_']]`.

My code does not work because the it always exits with a logical variable at the end of the list. I check the debug and saw it exit like this:

```
Exit: (12) pick_slots([], [['_'], ['_', '_', '_'], ['_'], ['_']|_G3154869]) ? skip
```

I have no idea how to make `_G3154869` `[]`. Any solution? Thank you.

Comment: Please include your code for split/3 as well. The cause of your problem may well be in that predicate.

Comment: why is that called 'logic variable'? is there a course somewhere or are you the same guy as sand?

Comment: What does `pick_slots([], _).` say? It says, *If you pick the slots from `[]`, you get a "don't care"*. Does that sound right? What should it really be? What should  you get if you pick slots from `[]`?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is why there is a variable in the rest of the list.  This is know as a **partial list**. Now, that is easy to answer:

First, consider the fact: In that case, the second argument is a free variable - which is a **partial list**, too.

Then, consider the rule and read it right-to-left: We assume that `R2` is a partial list in `pick_slots(Rest, R2)`. Because of this, also `R` will be a partial list - regardless of what `Result` is about.